# Not able to display web Form For Marketer in Sitecore 7.5

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.5

I have uploaded WFFM 2.5 version of web form and using sitecore 7.5 . I added placeholder and choose Datasource for form placehoder but form is not displaying in Page editor/preview mode.

Answer (score 0):

simply you need to create Layout in your sitecore and VS application, after creating  layout Render your place holder on the Layout as:

```
  // MVC Layout
  @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("content")
```

and give presentation this form and layout where you want to show you form, you don't need to give datasource .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sitecore MVC then you should select **Mvc Form** instead of **Form**.

Render the placeholder on your MVC layout as:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("content")
```

and make sure this placeholder allowed Mvc Form controls in Placeholder Settings.

Add the Mvc Form controls to your content item with this placeholder and on the edit mode set the FormID field with the form that you created.

I suggest to add the Data Source field as well, you just need to copy the path from FormID field then paste it to Data Source field. Don't forget to add backslash "/" char in the front of the path. (i.e. /sitecore/system/Modules/...)